# How can I stop Windows Firefox (V 69.0.2 64-bit) asking to save passwords when I log on to sites?

Tags: firefox

I have tried all the suggestions (except fiddling in the Registry) from Firefox's user group about how to stop Firefox asking if I want to save the password that I am entering. No effect that I can see. Replying "Never" doesn't seem to do anything either. It just keeps on asking. Ideas?

Comment: Stack overflow isn't really the best place for your question about firefox.

Comment: [Disabling the Password Manager](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/password-manager-remember-delete-edit-logins?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=password-manager-remember-delete-change-passwords#w_disabling-the-password-manager)